# @media print not working with display:none

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

I've been scratching my head for a couple hours over this and for the life of me I cannot figure out why it's not working. I have a Wordpress site where I want to hide the header, menu, and footer content from being printed. In my theme's style.css file, there is a section at the very bottom called `@media print` where all the print-specific styles are stored. I tried adding the following inside this section:

```
#search-box-wrap,
#search-box,
#inner-header,
#site-heading,
#site-generator,
#header,
#menu,
#sidebar,
#footer {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Basically all of these ids are the header/menu/footer div ids in my Wordpress site.

And my stylesheet link is as follows:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />`

A lot of topics I found suggested taking the `media` parameter out of the stylesheet link above (which I've done) because when you include the print styles with your regular stylesheet, you can't just use the `media="screen"` attribute...which makes sense, but I don't understand why it still does not work?

When I go to Print Preview or use my Web Developer Toolbar to view Print-Only CSS Styles, I still see the header/menu/footer sections even with this code added in my style.css file. Can anyone help me with why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use this styles for print then you should add `media="print"`, see below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" media="print" />
```

See more about media types [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html)

> **print**
>
> Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in print preview mode. Please consult the section on paged media for
>   information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.

**UPDATE:** After a discussion with OP, this what worked

- try linking directly without PHP codes

Comment: But because my print styles are contained within the same file (all in style.css) I thought I can't use the `media="print"` parameter? Also yes, my CSS above is wrapped inside my `@media print { }` query!

Comment: can you provide the url?

Comment: sorry for late reply, my advice to you is to cut the print styles from your main css styles, create a new one **print.css** add `media="print"` instead of `all` to your `link rel` and just add the styles normally without  wrapping `media`s

Comment: I tried doing as you suggested, by putting my print styles in a file called `styles-print.css` and referencing both CSS files separately in my `header.php` file, but it still doesn't work: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory_uri'); ?>/styles-print.css" />`

Comment: I went to your site couldn't find any `media="print"`

Comment: I don't think my stylesheet reference is correct - I am trying to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri to retrieve the directory URI (I am using a child theme) but it's not working...I can see `media="print"` in my view>source but the link is not correct and I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: When I link directly without codes, it works. 2 questions though - why doesn't it work using get_stylesheet_directory_uri (I assume I used bad syntax) and also now when I do print preview it hides the header, menu and footer but still shows all the links...how do I hide those sections completely? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83985/discussion-between-dippas-and-iconoclast).